# Subject Verb Agreement

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, subjects

In the email I received from IELTS notifying my results, I think the subject 'results' is not agreeing with the verb 'is' here. Can you please tell me if my understanding is correct.

The text I received is

> This is to inform you that the IELTS results for the test you sat on Sunday 1 December 2019 is now available on the Test Taker Portal.

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: This is a cringe-worthy irony.

Comment: Hello, Siva. 'Notify' almost always takes a human referent as object. '... notifying me of my results'.

Comment: Okay Edwin :) thank you for the correction. And can you also let me know about the sentence whether my understanding is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But in casual conversation the obvious object is often understood and can be elided.

Comment: @SivaKumarKakara Your understanding is very correct. There also should be a comma after "Sunday".

Comment: @Barmar This is possibly a US-UK divide. But before posting the comment,  I did check on the internet and found  few hits for "notify/notified my results" that seemed both in sound grammatical context and non-textspeak. And we are (hopefully) concerning ourselves with standard grammar here, as per the IELTS reference.